# this = this in decompiled Java

Tags: java, this, decompiling

I tried decompiling a Java application to which I do not have the source code and a strange thing showed up.  At the top of the constructor for a class, there is a line that says

```
this = this
```

What does *this* (not **this**) mean?  Is this just an artifact of the decompilation process?  Or is it just some ugly hack?  Can **this** be assigned to something else?  If so, what does

```
this = null
```

mean?

Comment: It might be useful to say which decompiler - it's not legal Java. Also javap -c will give you the actual bytecodes.

Comment: (Is it an inner class setting the outer instance?)

Comment: There is a chance, that the bytecode is obfuscated to prevent decompiling. Using illegal variable names like Java keywords is a nice practice...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29

Comment: is it common for the product of a decompiler to not compile?

Comment: Maybe try http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ to check if it produces the same results !?

Comment: @Victor, if the bytecode is obfuscated in some manner that the decompiler cannot understand, sure.

Comment: I second Andreas_D's suggestion - jd-gui is the best tool I've found for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is final.  You definitely cannot assign it.  I'd guess this is a disassembler artifact.

There's some potential goofy-ness with inner classes (which hold `this` pointers to the outer class), but those lines as written are not valid Java.